# How to count the number of objects in a specific area?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on vehicles detection, I used Yolo for detection and tracking vehicles now I want to calculate the number of detected vehicles in a specific area, I painted the rectangle where I want to count :

```
    cv2.rectangle(image, point, (point[0] + 200, point[1] + 120), (0, 0, 255), 0)
```

and detected vehicles are surrounded by a rectangle.
In an easy way, I want to calculate the number of rectangles included in a big rectangle

Comment: There is a tutorial on this at the [opencv page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html)

Comment: Can you just simply iterate all small rectangles and count only those with left-top point >= big rectangle left-top point and right-bottom point <= big rectangle right-bottom point?

Answer (score 0):

I just calculate the intersection of detection rectangle and the rectangle where I want to calculate the number.

```
    from collections import namedtuple
    Rectangle = namedtuple('Rectangle', 'xmin ymin xmax ymax')  
    def intersection(a, b):  # a and b are the 2 rectangle
    dx = min(a.xmax, b.xmax) - max(a.xmin, b.xmin)
    dy = min(a.ymax, b.ymax) - max(a.ymin, b.ymin)
    if (dx>=0) and (dy>=0):
       return dx*dy
```

if the result is > 0 that means there is intersection between the 2 rectangles.